# Where does Steam store files on Ubuntu?

Tags: files, steam, storage

Basically, every answer I've gotten just leads me to a script that LAUNCHES steam. I want to know where the actual files and stuff are stored so I can skin it, not how to find a file to run Steam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steam itself is located in `$HOME/.steam`. For the games, you can give it a different location during the installation.